# Anyone know the pull ratios of Zee 10sp and XT 9sp Mechs?

Tags: derailleur, shimano, shifter

I'm putting a bike together from a load of spares and I'm having difficulty getting a shifter and derailleer to play well. I think the problem is the Zee mech. Does anyone know the pitch/pull ratio in MM of the XT shifter compared to the Zee shifter? Ideally an answer 'from the horses mouth' would be good as I've read all sorts of conflicting info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shimano’s Dyna-Sys (10 speed MTB) products are only compatible with components in the Dyna-Sys lineup, from XTR to SLX. They are not compatible with any other parts. Use of a Dyna-Sys derailleur with 9-speed shifters is contraindicated.

Comment: Thanks zenbike. Any info on the actuall pull lengths/ratios? I know that some have managed to get SRAM stuff working and I'm trying to get a technical answer instead of a 'product blurb' answer that I keep seeing on the Shimano site and other reviews.

Comment: The ratios haven't been published for Dynasys. But it isn't just the ratio that prevents proper shifting.  It is also the travel path of the derailleur, which sits too far away from the cassette compared to a 9 speed derailleur. I've spent hours trying to make this work. It just doesn't.